# Is it possible to do something *after* something has finished in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple login page and I am trying to disable the username field, password field, and the submit button while I am authenticating, reenable them after if the password/username or both are wrong or simply login otherwise.

I am doing that using the following code:

```
    // get the field values
    var usernameField = document.getElementById("username");
    var passwordField = document.getElementById("password");
    var submit = document.getElementById("submit");

    usernameField.disabled = "disabled";
    passwordField.disabled = "disabled";
    submit.disabled = "disabled";

    // Authentication code
```

and I want everything to be disabled before the authentication code starts. For now, what it does is that when I click on the submit button, it remains "stuck" for few seconds then either logs in or simply produces the error. But it never disables anything (I made sure this is not a css problem).

Let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: Can you show your authentication code?

Comment: I assume that your authentication code goes via AJAX? The `stuck` part is the most interesting for me. Are you by any chance using a **synchronous** AJAX? That would explain a lot.

Comment: Use boolean values (`true`/`false`) to set the `disabled` property of elements.

Comment: It is not an issue of true/false (tried to disable everything the same way without authentication code (removed authentication code and simply disabled everything when submit is clicked) and everything worked fine

Comment: It's not at all clear why/what you're really trying to do. A typical approach would be to stop the submit from happening, authenticate the fields and then fire a new submit if it all worked out. Why do you want to disable the fields in this case?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: I am trying to disable the field while actually submitting the form (sending a request for authentication).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a callback function to your authentication code?  You could disable everything when submit is clicked, call the authentication code, and in the callback function re-enable your fields if the authentication fails.

Comment: That's what I am doing currently, the problem is that nothing is getting disabled (it gets stuck for a while then it either logs in or everything gets enabled again - if username is wrong for example)

Comment: Can you share the authentication code and any other relevant code?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I guess without providing the code, it is extremely hard to answer this question isn't it? sorry for that, will close the question if I can.

Comment: Yeah, it makes it pretty tough... The issue could be any number of places and without seeing it there is not much more I can do to help :/  Best of luck!